# Feature scaling in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a line chart. Right now I am using this

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.MEDV = +d.MEDV;
    d.CRIM = +d.CRIM;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.CRIM; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.MEDV; })).nice();
```

But I want to do feature scaling since my CRIM values varies from 0.006 to 88.

Comment: D3 doesn't do feature scaling for you. You could however use another scale to do it.

Comment: How do I change the scale then?

Comment: You don't change the scale, you use an additional one to scale the features.